# rails functional test will not destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a functional test that keeps failing and I'm not sure why. This is part of a forum and the test is to ensure that the author of a post is allowed to delete their own posts.

I am able to destroy the post in the console and in the browser when I try manually, I just can't figure out what is going wrong.

Here is the destroy action of the controller:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.player_id == current_player || current_player.admin == true # I can't delete anyone else's posts unless I am the administrator.
if @post.topic.posts_count > 1 # if topic is more than one post, delete just the post
    @post.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Post was successfully destroyed."
    redirect_to topic_path(@post.topic)
else # else, if the topic is only one post, delete the whole thing
  @post.topic.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Topic was successfully deleted."
  redirect_to forum_path(@post.forum)
    end
  else # You are not the admin or the topic starter
    flash[:notice] = "You do not have rights to delete this post."
    redirect_to topic_path(@post.topic)
  end
end
```

Here is the posts.yml file:

```
one:
  id: 1
  body: MyText
  forum_id: 1
  topic_id: 1
  player_id: 2
two:
  id: 2
  body: MyText
  forum_id: 1
  topic_id: 1
  player_id: 2
three:
  id: 3
  body: MyText
  forum_id: 1
  topic_id: 2
  player_id: 3
```

Here is the test that keeps failing:

```
test "should destroy post as author" do
  sign_in players(:player2)
  assert_difference('Post.count', -1) do # Line 41
    delete :destroy, :id => posts(:one)
  end
  assert_redirected_to topic_url(assigns(:topic))
end
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
1) Failure: test_should_destroy_post_as_author(PostsControllerTest) [../test/functional/posts_controller_test.rb:41]:
"Post.count" didn't change by -1.
<2> expected but was <3>.
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this. I feel like I'm hitting my head against a wall when I'm sure the answer is something simple that I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that particular wording is not working, but I fixed it so that when I destroy the post like I do in the console, the test passes.

Instead of: `delete :destroy, :id => @post`

I used: `Post.destroy(@post)`

Comment: As far as I know, this breaks the test's intention, because you are no longer sending a request to the controller.